# How do you test cookies in MVC .net?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/07/01/asp-net-mvc-tip-12-faking-the-controller-context.aspx

This post shows how to test setting a cookie and then seeing it in ViewData. What I what to do is see if the correct cookies were written (values and name). Any reply, blog post or article will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

Are you looking for something more like this?  (untested, just typed it up in the reply box)

```
var cookies = new HttpCookieCollection();
controller.ControllerContext = new FakeControllerContext(controller, cookies);
var result = controller.TestCookie() as ViewResult;
Assert.AreEqual("somevaluethatshouldbethere", cookies["somecookieitem"].Value);
```

As in, did you mean you want to test the writing of a cookie instead of reading one?
Please make your request clearer if possible :)

Comment: Those cookies belong to the request object and not the response object. I had already tried this.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need to pass in a Fake Response object that the cookies are written to, and you test what is returned in that from the Controller.

Answer (score -2):

```
function ReadCookie(cookieName) {
 var theCookie=""+document.cookie;
 var ind=theCookie.indexOf(cookieName);
 if (ind==-1 || cookieName=="") return ""; 
 var ind1=theCookie.indexOf(';',ind);
 if (ind1==-1) ind1=theCookie.length; 
 return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind+cookieName.length+1,ind1));
}
```